# ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom & Unload?

Tags: .net, reflection

If I do an `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom()`, is it possible to unload the assembly?

Or, can it be unloaded only if it is in a separate AppDomain, as with `Assembly.LoadFrom()` ?

I have a tool that needs to load an assembly for inspection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you need to load it into a separate AppDomain, then unload the entire AppDomain.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance in the new AppDomain and execute your code in that instance. Please see full example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37970043/797249