# .NET: Can I unload an assembly loaded for reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom & Unload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258165/reflectiononlyloadfrom-unload)

I know you can't noramlly unload assemblies in .NET without messing around with App Domains. But is there a way to unload it if I only load it for relection?

```
Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom
```

Comment: Yep, that's the answer. Bummer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no way to unload an assembly without unloading the AppDomain itself. See this question: [ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom & Unload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258165/reflectiononlyloadfrom-unload)