# Is it possible to inspect an assembly's IL instructions programmatically using managed code?

Tags: .net, disassembly, il

See title. Reflection.Emit seems to be more about creating a new dynamic assembly, not for loading an exisitng assembly and inspecting its IL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Common Compiler Infrastructure](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Played around with it a bit, very good. I can iterate through specific operations very easily using the sample code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[**Reflector**](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) does this, and last time I checked, Reflector could still inspect (i.e. disassemble) itself this way, so it will show you exactly how it works.

Comment: Does is provide an automation API or something?  As I said in the title I talking programmatically.  I don;t have the time currently to disassemble reflector.

Comment: Some possible options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425973/open-source-alternatives-to-reflector

Comment: CCI has libraries that you can use to achieve what you want. I have the link in my answer above.

Comment: @Code: Yeah, we see it. But thanks for pointing it out to us again anyway.