# .net disassembler tool like reflector

Tags: .net, reflector, .net-reflector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open Source Alternatives to Reflector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425973/open-source-alternatives-to-reflector)

Hi,

Does anyone know if there is a tool like reflector that can reflect .net code???
Since reflector is not free anymore, i want a replacement tool.

Answer (score 4):

ILSpy, [link](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx)

Telerik Just Decompile, [link](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiling.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Antonio for Telerik link.. it works beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

There is still a free version of Reflector available and I'm using it on a daily basis. Reflector is still your friend!

Update:

Red Gate [announced](http://www.reflector.net/2011/04/why-we-reversed-some-of-our-reflector-decision/) that Reflector 6.0 stays free and will not expire.

Comment: No man every time i oppen the reflector asks me to update to get the new version. If i click "No" the reflector doesn't open and if i click yes it is not free!!!!! The free version is not available anymore

Comment: @Gaby, I second that. It's not free anymore.

Comment: I had it yesterday, when I clicked on "No" for the update, the .exe was deleted from the hard drive. Very nice Red Gate!

Comment: I clicked "Yes" last week and it updated to the latest free version. It is still the free version. It has a banner at the bottom promoting the pro versino.

Comment: @Steven - if you hit yes last week, is it possible that you're in the 14 day trial period? It's quite well documented that it's no longer free: http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1

Comment: @Damien: The document you reference is about version 7. I am running version 6.6; no trial period. I just upgraded tot 6.6 last week. The comments here are a big warning. I prevent upgrading to v7. This sucks. Anyone has a reference to one of old versions that don't contain a timeout bomb?

Answer (score 0):

What about the good old ILDASM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

But there is

- monodis (part of mono, open source) which does what ildasm does
- monodevelopo (which decompiles code in the assembly reference browser)

A nice list of reflector [alternatives is here](http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/tag/ilspy/)

Answer (score 0):

A good list of alternatives is [here](http://www.adrianbanks.co.uk/?p=71)