# Where can I read up on what the C# compiler does?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

Throughout this site I commonly see people answer questions with such answers as "it works like that because the compiler replaces [thing] with [other thing]", so my question is, how do people know/learn this? Where can I learn these things?

Comment: You need to know the secret handshake.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/compiler

Comment: [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) and [Reflectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425973/open-source-alternatives-to-reflector)

Comment: ildasm will let you learn a lot about what the C# compiler produces, as you easily experiment and see what IL it emits.  You might also check out Roslyn, whose API reveals the perspective from which the compiler sees C# code.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most definitive source for how the C# compiler interprets code is the C# language spec.

- http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029

Also the following blogs provide a lot of more insight into the C# language.  Mandatory reading for anyone who wants to become an expert in the language

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/
- http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/

Comment: @GSerg I often think of the C# lang spec as "what the compiler is doing" and Eric's blog as "why the compiler is doing what it's doing"

Answer (score 2):

One technique is to compile your code, and then decompile it using tools such as [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx).  Using such a tool, you can view the raw IL and see for yourself what the compiler produces.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, I'd like to mention that [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is my favorite tool for inspecting IL for quick snippets.

You can type a snippet of code, and immediately see the IL.
It's by far the easiest tool to use, and you can make changes and see the results instantly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking the Intermediate Language and reading the language specification, please allow me to add "**CLR via C#**" by Jeffrey Richter.  Microsoft Press Library of Congress Control Number: 2009943026.  This reference is amazing, and goes into complete detail on what's happening under the covers.

Answer (score -1):

Niklaus Wirth's book [Compiler Construction (PDF)](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/wirth/CompilerConstruction/CompilerConstruction1.pdf) is an introduction to the theory and the techniques of compiler construction. It gives you a general idea of what a compiler is and what it does.

Comment: Updated the link to a new version of the PDF document.