# Retrieving the code from an executable file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reverse-engineering, decompiling, disaster-recovery

Due to some disasters, my source code is lost.

I now have only the cabinet file and the installer of my software.

So, I want to retrieve my code from my software to improve it as per current market trends.
The software has VB as a front end and Access as back end.

Please give me the solution, so that I can build that software again, because from beginning this is impossible to build that software again.

Comment: Obviously you should restore from your backups. Failing that, you can probably decompile the binaries and copy-paste the code. I felt sorry for [this guy who had the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875198/how-can-i-recover-data-code-from-visual-studio-2010-made-debug-folders), so I wrote out a long answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of code decompilation software, with the one example being [.NET Reflector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector).

Answer (score 0):

.Net Reflector: http://www.reflector.net/

But it's not that good enough, you might want a plugin like FileGenerator For Reflector: http://filegenreflector.codeplex.com/

I did it before and you may still need to edit your code as the reverse engineering is not good enough, but it should be OK within half an hour max to make it be able to complied. Or if you are lucky and you code not that complicated, you might just get the one exactly as you wrote