# Azure publish package content

Tags: azure

When I "publish" or "package" the Azure "cloud service" WCF that I have, does the publish or package actually include the source codes for my application or is just the binary that is getting published. Is there a way that Microsoft can see the code of my application? Is it safe to assume that the actual C# codes are not being published or be seen in the Microsoft server? If binary is being published, there is no way for a binary to be reverted back to source code right? I'm just trying to protect my intellectual property.

Comment: .Net assemblies can be easily decompiled.  However, I really don't think that Microsoft would do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binaries get deployed.

Any .NET library can be decompiled pretty trivially, though there are obfuscation tools that make the decompiled code more difficult to read (See [Open Source Alternatives to Reflector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425973/open-source-alternatives-to-reflector) for a discussion on open source decompilers).

Personally I wouldn't be concerned about Microsoft decompiling and stealing your IP. Anyway, any hosting provider would have similar access to your deployments.