# Is it possible to run inside visual studio .net published web site?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, web

Hello I need one confirmation from you guys.  I have one client who have published web site (asp.net 2.0) and site is live online. Client doesn't have solution or original source code of this web site project. My question is :  Is it possible to download this code localy and successively run it inside visual studio ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is Nope.

You do need the source code to build and run the web site within Visual Studio. Visual Studio purpose is to help the developer build the website or even extend a website (looks like what you want to do) and to do so it requires source code files.

What you can do is to try to set up [IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn) (Internet Information Services) and run a copy of the web site locally but it isn't Visual Studio as you stated in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much Leniel. I know this but I needed to ask again just to get some confirmation. I was not shore enough,thought maybe there is some solution in those days.

Comment: OK. It doesn't hurt to ask. :D

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you may find the source code files on the live server, or a backup of them.  If not you could use the dlls and [some software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425973/open-source-alternatives-to-reflector) to view the code using reflection.

Some of these also regenerate the Visual Studio projects for you - I know the paid version of .Net Reflector does.

If you do it that way, depending on what you use, some of the code may not come out exactly as it was written but it should work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it in cassini, iis, or iis express but you can't step through the code if that's what you're after.

If you want to simply inspect the code I recommend IL spy. That's what I use.

http://ilspy.net/