# how to edit method of dll file for asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have xgeno.mvc.utilities dll in my project references. I want to edit one of the method of this dll.

Can I do this?

Comment: You have to decompile the DLL and change your stuff inside that code. But take care: if it is not your code, for non-research purposes this is forbidden in a lot of countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a decompiler for this which has many variants on the web (there's google) and then make the modifications on the decomplied files and then compile it again and then point that newly compiled dll to your project

Comment: Thank you. I will try this solution,

Comment: No problem. You can at least hit this post as the answer if this worked for you

Answer (score 1):

You need something like .NET Reflector, but since it is not free, you will probably want to look for free alternatives. See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425973/open-source-alternatives-to-reflector) some discussion wich can help in the search.

Comment: Thank you. I will go through it