# How do I programmatically enumerate types in a running .NET process using MDbg?

Tags: c#, debugging, reflection, mdbg

I want to print out a list of all the different Types loaded in a running .NET process. My plan is to eventually build a GUI app based on this, so I want to do this from my code as opposed to a third party tool. I think my best bet is to use MDbgCore to attach to the running process, and then use MDbgProcess.AppDomains to get CorAppDomain objects, and try and walk the object model down.

However, I can't for the life of me stop the other process and see any AppDomains. I've been using code like the following (which I've based on code from [Mike Stall's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2004/11/19/267135.aspx))

```
    [MTAThread] // MDbg is MTA threaded
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MDbgEngine debugger = new MDbgEngine();

        debugger.Options.StopOnModuleLoad = true;

        // Launch the debuggee.            
        int pid = Process.GetProcessesByName("VS2010Playground")[0].Id;
        MDbgProcess proc = debugger.Attach(pid);
        if (proc.IsAlive)
        {
            proc.AsyncStop().WaitOne();

            Console.WriteLine(proc.AppDomains.Count);
            if (proc.AppDomains.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(proc.AppDomains[0].CorAppDomain);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }
```

This prints:

```
MDbgPlayground.exe
0
Done!
```

I've tried various flavours of debugger.Options.Stop*. I've thought of iterating over all the methods and setting breakpoints on all of them, but I can't iterate over the Modules list either. I've tried debugger.Options.Trace, but that's to do with tracing execution of MDbg using TraceListeners, not tracing the target app.

I'm running my noddy debugger app in release mode, and the target in debug mode. I'm using Visual C# 2010, and I'm at my wit's end. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Just doing some tinkering, try something like this (you may need to modify as necesary)...

```
        foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            try
            {
                Assembly test = Assembly.LoadFrom(process.MainModule.FileName);
                Console.WriteLine(test.FullName);

                foreach (Type type in test.GetTypes())
                    Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
            }
            catch
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's not going to work - that will only show the types defined in the main assembly of that process, not the types that are loaded into that process at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be so easy. I don't have specific source code for this problem, but I would pseudo-code it like this:

- Do a stop on the Mdbg process
- Setup a new AppDomain (mixed apps can have .NET2 and .NET4 assemblies, so reflecting on them in the current appdomain may throw an exception!!)

  System.AppDomain tempDomain=System.AppDomain.CreateDomain("ReflectionOnly");
- Iterate through MDbgProcess.Modules and load them into the appdomain for reflection-only using Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad (see [How to load a .NET assembly for reflection operations and subsequently unload it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225330/how-to-load-a-net-assembly-for-reflection-operations-and-subsequently-unload-it))
- Iterate through the assemblies in tempDomain
- For each assembly, get a list of types
- Report the Type.Name
- Unload tempDomain
- Invoke MDbgProcess.Go

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons you should use `debugger.Processs.Active` instead of `proc` variable.
Also you should call `debugger.Go()` before `AsyncStop`. So final code

```
[MTAThread] // MDbg is MTA threaded
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MDbgEngine debugger = new MDbgEngine();

    debugger.Options.StopOnModuleLoad = true;

    // Launch the debuggee.            
    int pid = Process.GetProcessesByName("VS2010Playground")[0].Id;
    MDbgProcess proc = debugger.Attach(pid);
    proc.Go();
    if (proc.IsAlive)
    {
        proc.AsyncStop().WaitOne();

        Console.WriteLine(debugger.Process.Active.AppDomains.Count);
        if ((debugger.Process.Active.AppDomains.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((debugger.Process.Active.AppDomains[0].CorAppDomain);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
}
```