# Bug with AppDomain.Unload?

Tags: appdomain

I've implemented code simlar to the 4th answer in [How to load a .NET assembly for reflection operations and subsequently unload it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225330/how-to-load-a-net-assembly-for-reflection-operations-and-subsequently-unload-it)

When I try to load two assemblies, one debug and the other release, I get a FileLoadException, with the message saying "It cannot be loaded from a new location within the same appdomain"

The code I'm using is:

```
private String rootAssembly;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rootAssembly = "{...path to release version...}\TestApp.exe";
    TempLoadAssembly();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rootAssembly = "{...path to debug version...}\TestApp.exe";
    TempLoadAssembly();
}

public void TempLoadAssembly()
{
    AppDomain tempDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TemporaryAppDomain");
    tempDomain.DoCallBack(LoaderCallback);
    AppDomain.Unload(tempDomain);
}

private void LoaderCallback()
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(rootAssembly);
    IList<CustomAttributeData> customAttributeDatas = CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes(assembly);
    // do other work here
}
```

Is there a bug in my code, or is it not posssible to load two versions of an assembly?  I'm calling AppDomain.Unload() on the new temp domain to sidestep this issue but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Check that in your `LoaderCallback` you dont accidentally allow the assembly to be loaded in the primary domain. You can see if this happens in the debugger output.

Comment: To load two assemblies with the same full name (as in your case) from different paths switch from Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom to Assembly.LoadFile. Note though that the dependencies of these assemblies will not be automatically resolved. You will have to do this by subscribing to the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event.

Comment: Leppie, I'm not sure how to check this.  The debug output window isn't telling me which app domain the assembly is being loaded in.  Also, from what I've read, by creating a new domain and a callback, and then placing the laod within the callback, the loading is supposed to take place within that callback's app domain.

Comment: Panos, for my project, LoadFile() is out and I need to use ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom().  I'm writing a tool which gathers the information of assemblies (like if it's debug or not, assembly version, etc...).  LoadFile() attempts to load the assembly, where as ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom() is a little more light weight and allows the attributes of an assembly to be examined w/o having to fully load it.  I went this route because if the app is built with one version of .NET, and then examines an app built with a newer version, the assembly tries to be loaded and an exception is thrown.

Comment: Also, I should point out that to reproduce this, simply create a new WinForms project, add two buttons to the main form, then add the code I've posted above.  I've tried this in different versions of .NET and different versions of VisualStudio, and I always get the same results.