# How to Extract the Resouce Content From MSIL OR .NET PE Files

Tags: .net, portable-executable, disassembly, ilspy

Please check the Image link, i need to extract the resource content from the MSIL file. I have debugged the file using ILSpy but i need to do it in any other way. with out using any manual intereption.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQdRc.png

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Are you trying to do this with code? Why isn't ILSpy sufficient?

Comment: i need to extract more files around 20+. I cannot open every files in ILspy and extract in manually. Any command line type required. Eg. Extracter.exe <MSILFile.exe or Directory>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with something like:

```
public class LoadAssemblyInfo : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }

    public Tuple<string, byte[]>[] Streams;

    public void Load()
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(AssemblyName);

        string[] resources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

        var streams = new List<Tuple<string, byte[]>>();

        foreach (string resource in resources)
        {
            ManifestResourceInfo info = assembly.GetManifestResourceInfo(resource);

            using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                streams.Add(Tuple.Create(resource, bytes));
            }
        }

        Streams = streams.ToArray();
    }
}

// Adapted from from http://stackoverflow.com/a/225355/613130
public static Tuple<string, byte[]>[] LoadAssembly(string assemblyName)
{
    LoadAssemblyInfo lai = new LoadAssemblyInfo
    {
        AssemblyName = assemblyName,
    };

    AppDomain tempDomain = null;

    try
    {
        tempDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TemporaryAppDomain");
        tempDomain.DoCallBack(lai.Load);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (tempDomain != null)
        {
            AppDomain.Unload(tempDomain);
        }
    }

    return lai.Streams;
}
```

Use it like:

```
var streams = LoadAssembly("EntityFramework");
```

`streams` is an array of `Tuple<string, byte[]>`, where `Item1` is the name of the resource and `Item2` is the binary content of the resource.

It is quite complex because it does the `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad` in another `AppDomain` that is then unloaded (`AppDomain.CreateDomain`/`AppDomain.Unload`).